# Sometimes no sound over headphone jack on Dell E6530 on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, headphones, headphone-jack

I have a Dell E6530 Laptop with Windows 8.1 64 Bit and the newest sound driver installed (IDT 92HD93 High-Definition Audio Driver 3330_Audio_Driver_C6HVR_WN_1.0.6491.0_A08).

Sometimes after booting I only get sound when no headphone is plugged in but as soon as it is, there is no sound neither over speakers nor over headphones. Rebooting some times cures this problem but it soon comes again.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same issue on Latitude E6530.

Sometime when I pull out the headphones the sound stops working in the speakers and then plugging in the headphones don't work either.

Have you found a solution to this issue.

Only reinstalling the sound drivers and a reboot seems to fix the issue temporarily.

I have gone back to A06 which I think does not have the issue.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/aubsd1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=RPG74&fileId=3327984030&osCode=W864&productCode=latitude-e6530&categoryId=AU

More information here
http://stealthpuppy.com/dell-owners-avoid-the-idt-92hdxxx-hd-audio-driver/

Comment: For me a few reboots temporarily fix it, a reinstallation is not necessary in my case.

Comment: Sorry I was not trying to answer the question but to comment on it. I should of used the add a comment and not answer.

Comment: Does it happen when using Spotify. Apparently spotify cannot handle switching between output device once it is running. http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/There-is-a-problem-with-your-sound-card-Spotify-can-t-play-music/td-p/664164

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Dell.  What was happening was the default sound device was not switching to the proper device/port when headphones where plugged in.  Part of the issue was I was using a D-port to my monitors that had integrated audio (similar to some HDMI) and the sound was playing on the monitor jack instead of my headphone jack on the computer.  So I ended up right clicking on the speaker down near the clock --> playback devices --> Click on the port you want to be the default --> click set as default.  I know what your thinking, they both say Speakers which one is it?  Play some music and you will see the green bar jumping on the output that should be making sound.  If you don't hear sound, set the other device as the default.  For instance, in my example.  The top speaker are my monitor speakers, the bottom, the built in laptop speakers.
[image: Sound Default Playback Device Settings]